# Shorthand Notation of Partial Derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

My professor told us that the following  partial derivatives  $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ can be represented as $D_z$ and $D_z'$ respectively where $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ . Similarly $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}= D_zD_z'$

But I have been wondering what would be $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ in this particular shorthand Notation.

I tried searching in Wikipedia and some online sites but I couldn't get the answer.

Comment: This notation is odd because neither $D_z$, nor $D'_z\,,$ tells us with respect to which variable we differentiate.